# Lead Trigger and lead.addError()

Tags: trigger, leads, duplicate-management, adderror, allornone

I have this problem with triggers:

We have integration with our backoffice to receive leads. Unfortunately, we can't change this integration. It sends the leads when when it shouldn't.

On `insert` if I find an existing duplicate lead I don't want to insert it. I do `lead.addError('This lead already exists in the system')` and it works fine.

The problem is that I also need to create a task for this existing lead owner saying something along the lines of

> user submitted the form again

This task is an important signal for the sellers and they want to be notified when that happens. The problem is that if I do `addError()` in the trigger it rolls everything back and doesn't insert my task.

**How can I prevent the lead from being inserted while creating a task at the same time?**

Or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Would be easier for us if we could see the code and what it is that you have done so far. If you are working with a trigger and you are rolling back I think is necessary for us to see that code before giving you any direction that may help you. I can't see why you can't send Tasks if a record fails. There are ways to control and build logic around falling records.

Comment: Platform event can still be published event if entire transaction rolled back. Based on that you can log a task in separate execution context

Comment: @kurunve, how would you set up a separate context in a trigger ?

Comment: But firing a platform event (with Publish Immediately option - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_events.htm&type=5) and creating task then in event trigger or maybe process builder

Comment: You can also put a Savepoint after creating the Task so it doesn't matter if you rollback after that, the task creation will be preserved.

Comment: Hi Alex! Yes, you are right, I haven't thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kurunve suggested it is indeed possible to do this with a platform event with "publish immediately" option and a process builder.

1. Create a platform event and some custom fields that you'll need to create a task or whatever object you need.
2. In the lead trigger before you do .addError() publish your platform event. It can look something along these lines:

   ```
   Database.SaveResult sr = EventBus.publish(new ABTask__e(
       AccountOwnerID__c = ownerId,
       Account_ID__c = accountId
   ));
   if (sr.isSuccess()) {
       System.debug('Successfully published event.');
   } else {
       for (Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
           System.debug('Error returned: ' + err.getStatusCode() + ' - ' + err.getMessage());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Subscribe to your event. You can do it in a trigger on after insert or with a Process Builder.
4. Voilà, you can insert/update records independent of the trigger context.